# Can't delete any comments models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Deleting other stuff works fine. It looks the same as my post controller (which is working) but doesn't delete the comments.

```
resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

**_comment partial**

```
<% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
  <%= link_to "[Delete]", comment, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

**comments controller**

```
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    # @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Comment deleted"    
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
    end
```

Comment: Could you add your routes please

Comment: Do you get an error or something?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what happens? Some detail would be useful.

Comment: absolutely nothing happens. no error. it just redirects to @post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `before_action :correct_user` is redirecting the request before the the `@comment.delete` gets called in the `destroy` action.

```
def correct_user
  @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
  # This line below is the problem.
  redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end
```

Some other things that you can improve:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

[`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) is redundant here. If you are using the `id` to fetch the record, use [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).

```
@comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
```

`find` also has the benefit of raising an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error, which translates to a 404 not found response in production.

If you want to redirect back, you don't need to do this:

```
  redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
```

You can just do [`redirect_to :back`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html), which is in Rails.

Finally, I would rename your `correct_user` to `set_comment`. I don't think `correct_user` expresses the intention of the code, which is to load the comment. You should end up with this:

```
before_action :set_comment, only: :destroy

def destroy
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end

def set_comment
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
end
```